# Determining V and I from limited data

Tags: induction-motor, phasor, single-phase, reactive-power

I am the recipient of an incomplete set of data for several 120 volt, single phase, AC drive systems driving induction motors under various loads. The measurements were taken at the AC voltage source. I do not have a way to take more or better measurements so am forced to work with data I have. The only data I have available to me is:

1. Watts (true power)
2. VA (apparent power)
3. Frequency (60 Hz)

From this I have calculated the following:

1. Power factor
2. Phase angle
3. VAR (reactive power)

My goal is to figure out AC volts or AC current. Is it possible for me to obtain this from this limited data set? One major problem is that the wire run to these drive systems was very long so I am certain that the voltage measured at the drive was sagging under load at some times.

I could provide the numbers if that helps, but I don't think it'll be necessary since I would like to know how to do the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't enough information to figure out exact AC voltage or current. You will have to assume a value for V or I.  You could graph I for a range of V=100-120. That will give you a reasonable range of possible values for I taking possible voltage sag into account.

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I thought. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something though.

Answer (score 1):

If I told you that a machine was turning a shaft and producing 1000 watts of mechanical power into a mechanical load, would you be able to tell me the torque or the speed?

The answer is no because, all you can say is that power = \$n T\$ where n is radians per second and T is torque. You don't know anything about the ratio of n to T.

Answer (score 1):

If by "AC drive systems," you mean variable frequency drives (VFDs), the input current waveform will be significantly distorted. The input VA measurement will not be accurate unless it is based on a true RMS measurement of the current waveform. The input watts measurement will not be accurate unless if is is affected by the harmonic content. The power factor can be defined in two ways: The total power factor is true power / true RMS VA. The displacement power factor is true power / fundamental VA. Phase angle has meaning only for the fundamental components of the waveform.

You need to know the characteristics of the instruments before you know what you have. Once you know what you have, you can only estimate what you would like to know.

With distortion, there is a power box as shown below, rather than a power triangle. The effect of distortion VA is similar to the effect of reactive VA, but they can not simply be added together. They add vectorial as shown. In considering the effect on the total system, the VA from all of the undistorted load currents can be added together. All of the distortion VA components must be added together separately.

[image]

VFDs often have harmonic current distortion remediation built in. Since the displacement power factor is very high, they do not have power factor correction, but distortion reduction has a similar effect. Conventional power factor compensation should not be added. Existing power factor compensation capacitors can sometimes be converted to harmonic traps by adding resistors and/or inductors.

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you for this answer. The measurements I received were true RMS measurements. Just to make sure I understand and that I was clear, the measurements I received were taken between the AC input and the motor drive.I also have scope shots and they vary a lot depending on the drive system under test as some appear to have power factor correcting devices within them and some clearly do not.

Comment: I expanded my answer.